# Running python file from root of the project gives filenotfounderror

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is my project structure:

```
- MyProject
  - src
     - Master.py
     - Myfolder
        - file1
     - Myfolder2
        - file2
```

when i tried to run `python3 Master.py` from `src` folder i get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No Module name 'src'
```

when i tried to run Master.py from root using this command -> `python3 -m src.Master`

i get `file1 Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

My master.py has this import - `from src.myfolder import file1`

so it looks like that my Master.py is running from the root of the project but then it does not pick the imports that are in Master.py. I already tried to add empty init.py file in root of the project as well as `src` and `myfolder`but it does not work. I would appreciate any help !

Comment: might just be my ignorance, but aren't you importing a folder? and not a file?

Comment: @Datanovice in master.py i am importing file1 that sits in src.myfolder

Comment: I think you're missing `__init__.py` file in your src module

Comment: @Flo i already added init.py file in myfolder as well as in root of the project but no luck

Comment: @Flo i tried adding __init__.py in src as well but still not working

Comment: in `src.myfolder` did you add a `__init__.py` that contains a declaration for file1 ?  By the way what is `file1` ? A function? A Class? A Variable?

Comment: Can you provide the full file structure with every file that's in `src`. Also the full contents of `Master.py`

Comment: @blueteeth i have updated full folder structure in my question

Comment: @Flo in my master.py i am creating a master dictionary like this- `master_dict={'file1': file1.main()}` it calls a main function in file1. In __init_.py i have added this `from src.myfolder import file1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the updated directory structure, you should add an `__init__.py` file to `myfolder` with the following line:

```py
from .file1 import * # or 
# from .file1 import something # or 
# from . import file1
```

and then in `master.py` do

```py
import myfolder # or
# from myfolder import file1 # or
# from myfolder.file1 import something
```

Comment: my `master.py` has this import already - `from src.myfolder import file1`

Comment: I've updated my answer given the updated directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

While my solution worked with what was suggested by Maxim i also learned that with the help of simple `os.chdir(os.path.dirname('/usr/dirname'))` i was able to resolve the issue and i also did not have to add `__init__.py` anywhere in the package